# Bash Shell Scripting - Find duplicate named files on different directories

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, duplicates, msys

I have several **files** and **folders** on different directories which I'm quite positive they have been renamed on those other directories with **capitalized letters**.

I wanted to be able to find those duplicately named files and folders on the different directories and sort them out so I can see and then track them down afterwards.

Something like:

```
C:\Program Files\hello.txt

C:\WhateverFolder\heLlo.txt
```

This would be the output of the program or something similar to that.

You guys think it's possible?

Comment: This may help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20248082/binary-compare-all-files-against-all-files-in-a-specified-directory-and-subdire/20248223#20248223

Comment: Unfortunately, no, it didn't help me, sorry :/ Either I'm too much of a "noob" or I couldn't make that work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find /directory | awk '{names[gensub(".*/","","g")]++} END { for (name in names) { if (names[name] > 1) { print name } } }'
```

Might give you a list of duplicate names (files and folders). That gives you a starting point.

The above assumes `gawk`, so here is a more general solution which even supports mixed-case filenames, kudos to [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21383256/bash-shell-scripting-find-duplicate-named-files-on-different-directories/21384119#comment32257158_21384119) for the idea:

```
find /directory | awk -F '/' '{names[tolower($NF)]++} END { for (name in names) { if (names[name]>1) { print name }}}'
```

Comment: Well, maybe you can solve this now: It says "awk" does not exist. How would I make it exist?

Comment: @Gabriel: Assuming you're on Windows (which your example paths suggest), you need a Unix compatibility layer such as [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS)

Comment: @Zsolt: Beautiful `akw`ery, but (a) you're missing `}}` at the end, and (b) you're assuming `gawk`; a variant of your command that should work on more platforms is: `find /directory | awk -F '/' '{names[$NF]++} END { for (name in names) { if (names[name]>1) { print name }}}'`

Comment: @mklement0: Yes, I am using Windows and thanks for that comment, using the Unix compatibility layer made it easier and accomplishable along with your other comment on what was missing at Zsolt's comment.

Comment: @Gabriel: Glad to hear it - one other thing to note: the matching is not case-INsensitive, as your question stipulates. To make it so, use `find /directory | awk -F '/' '{names[tolower($NF)]++} END { for (name in names) { if (names[name]>1) { print name }}}' - one caveat there: MSYS currently has no Unicode support, so this won't work with foreign chars. (Curiously, even the `awk` versions on at least a few Unix platforms lack Unicode support.)

Comment: @mklement0 thanks for improving my answer, if you don't mind I had edited your solution to it.

Comment: @ZsoltBotykai: You're welcome - thanks for updating your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If Unix-y commands are too much for you, you can get a listing like this and sort it out yourself maybe?

```
DIR /B /S /L  somefolder
```